# Declare empty array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, eval

**update**

My code that works. When page is loaded

```
    product= [[],[]];
```

then the code executed after ajax call:

```
$('#contextreload ul').each(function(i, ul) {
product.push([]);
});

$('#contextreload ul').each(function(i, ul) {
  allline=i; 
  $('#reloadajax'+i+' li').each(function(lk, li) {
  var lilk = $(li).html();  product[i][lk]=lilk;

  // your code goes here
 });

  // your code goes here
});
```

To use eval(); in ajax response for this, with some changes in php file?
**/endupdate**

product[0]=[1,2,3,4];

product[1]=[a,b,x,z];

.

.

product[10]=[extra,extra,extra,extra];

When I load the page this is executed: `product= [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];`

But if I declare this, when I call ajax I can <strike>push</strike> add data only to this array (10 rows)
If I have 11 rows (`product[10][0]` and `product[10][1]`), the extra data will not be added.
After ajax call I need the extra data
 : `product= [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],**[11]**];`

This function is because I want to put data in array after loading ajax data from php file.

```
$('#contextreload ul').each(function(i, ul) {
 <strike> var product = $(ul).html();  </strike>
    allline = i; 

    $('#reloadajax'+i+' li').each(function(lk, li) {
        var lilk = $(li).html();  
        product[i][lk]=lilk;
        alert(lilk+lk);
        // your code goes here
    });
    // your code goes here
});


}
```

Comment: Why pre-allocate/dimension? Create a basic empty array `=[];` then `.push` to it in the loop as needed

Comment: I change the data after ajax call. First time I have 2 rows with data. After the call there can be 10 rows.

Comment: @user3944364 Post the code of your ajax call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the succes of your ajax call use the function [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
product.push([]);
```

This adds an array at the last index of `product`. Like that ,the index `10` is created and you have an extra data.

If you want to add a dynamic number of rows, use this code :

```
var number_of_new_row = 11; // 11 for example, you can use any number >= 0
for(; number_of_new_row--;)
    product.push([]);
```

---

**Another way**

In your ajax return save the new length of your array `product` in a global variable.
And use it before your loop to reset your array and initialize it with the new length.

```
var lengthArray = 10; // update the value in the callback of your ajax call
```

And your loop :

```
var product = [];
for(; lengthArray--;)
    product.push([]);

$('#contextreload ul').each(function(i, ul) {
    //<strike> var product = $(ul).html();  </strike>
    allline = i; 

    $('#reloadajax'+i+' li').each(function(lk, li) {
        var lilk = $(li).html();  
        product[i][lk]=lilk;
        alert(lilk+lk);
        // your code goes here
    });
    // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: I want to rewrite the array. I think my function is wrong with this line   product[i][lk]=lilk; . Mabe product[i]=[var,var,var,var]; is right. I need to rethink the loop

Comment: @user3944364 I added another way in my answer.

Comment: Works $('#contextreload ul').each(function(i, ul) {
    product.push([]);
});  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Note: this line of your code produces a string, not an array.

```
var product = $(ul).html();  //returns string not an array
```

what you need is something like

```
var product_arr = {}; // an object or 
var product_arr = []; // an array
```

Comment: `{}` defines an object and not an array. `[]` is more appropriate

Comment: thats right R3tep. that was what I meant on the 2nd line

Answer (score 2):

The following code used to declare empty array in javascript

```js
var product_arr = new Array(); //declaring empty array

console.log(product_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var product = [];
```

was the answer I was looking for personally